# How to return dictionary formatting？

Tags: python

How to return dictionary formatting

```
ret = {'organize_code': 'organize_code', 'desc': 'desc', 'name': '姓名', 'id': 'ID'}
```

expect

```
ret = {
    'organize_code': 'organize_code',
    'desc': 'desc',
    'name': '姓名',
    'id': 'ID'
}
```

i tried `json.dumps(ret, indent=1)` but i have chinese in data.
it likes this that Not what I expected.

```
{
 "id": "ID",
 "desc": "desc",
 "organize_code": "organize_code",
 "name": "\u59d3\u540d"
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to return the dictionary with the chinese characters in their correct format?

Comment: Are you just talking about printing it out, then you can look at the standard [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#pprint.pprint) function.

Comment: Looks perfectly valid JSON to me - representing characters outside of ASCII range in strings as `\uXXXX` is essentially the only way when you don't know how resulting string will be used/transferred... Some clarification why you don't like it would help (along with desired usage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ensure_ascii=False` to allow output non-ASCII characters:

```
>>> ret = {'organize_code': 'organize_code', 'desc': 'desc', 'name': '姓名', 'id': 'ID'}
>>> print(json.dumps(ret,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False))
{
    "organize_code": "organize_code",
    "desc": "desc",
    "name": "姓名",
    "id": "ID"
}
```